# Unexpected character (j) at position 67

Tags: java, json

I have a json file which contains json array representing some shapes like that,

```
[{"Cordinates":  [272.0,81.0,200.0,100.0],
  "Type":"Ellipse2D",
  "Color":java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]},
 {"Cordinates":[227.0,272.0,200.0,100.0],
  "Type":"Rectangle2D",
  "Color":java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]}
]
```

the errors

```
Unexpected character (j) at position 67.
```

And here is my code to parse this

```
public List<ShapeItem> read() {     
    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(filePath));
        JSONArray ja = (JSONArray)obj;          
        for (int j = 0; j < ja.size(); j++){
             JSONObject si = (JSONObject) ja.get(j);
             String type = (String) si.get("Type");             
             JSONArray cordinates = (JSONArray) si.get("Cordinates");
             Float x, y, width, height;
             x = (Float) cordinates.get(0);
             y = (Float) cordinates.get(1);
             width = (Float) cordinates.get(2);
             height = (Float) cordinates.get(3);
             if (type.equals("Ellipse2D")){
                s = new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
             }
             else if (type.equals("Rectangle2D")){
                s = new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
             }
             c = (Color) si.get("Color");
             shapeItem = new ShapeItem(s, c);
             shapes.add(shapeItem);
        }   
     }  
      return shapes;
  }
```

I want to read this file and create those shapes and return array of shapes but i got errors any help?

Comment: _but i got errors_ Is that **all** you have to say or would you like to tell us **which** errors?

Comment: It would also help if you could tell us which JSON parser do you use.

Comment: That is not an error your posted. It is a stack trace _without_ the error message.

Comment: You should not cut of the exception message ...

Comment: As @MichaelKrause has suggested, that is not valid JSON.

Comment: Use this page to validate your JSON: http://jsonlint.com/. Come back if you have a valid JSON and your code still doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A JSON object attribute that describes a single value should be a key-value pair where the value is one of the valid JSON attribute value types such as a string or a number.

However, your Color attribute does not have a value that can be turned into either of these.

Specifically:

```
"Color":java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
```

Is in no way valid JSON.

Try specifying your color like this instead:

```
"Color":"#ffff0000"
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Very good point.  I could have done a better job of clarifying the first time around.  I've modified the answer to better accommodate the ability to specify a variety of different types for an attribute value.

Comment: so how would i store color in json

Comment: You could represent it as a color string of the form "#aarrggbb" or an integer value encoding the argb you want.